# Allow Properties to be any string

Tags: json, validation, schema

Given the following json document:

```
{
    "property-1": {
        "server": "string-value",
        "environment": "string-value",
        "cluster": "string-value"
    },
    "property-2": {
        "server": "string-value",
        "environment": "string-value",
        "cluster": "string-value"
    }
}
```

I am busy doing up a json schema for this type of json document where `property-1` can be any string, but inside of that, we will have a set structure with a number of required. What I am struggling with is how to define the schema so that the user will be able to set any string for `property-1 | property-2`.

I assume I have to use a pattern, but what I have tried haven't worked that well.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "role": {
            "$id": "#svcrole",
            "description": "Application name for which role is required.",
            "type": "object",
            "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z\\-]+$",
            "properties": {
                "server": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "environment": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "cluster": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "server",
                "environment",
                "cluster"
            ]
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "$schema": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "$name": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/role"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I stumbled upon the solution here.

You want to use `propertyNames` and `patternProperties` like:

```
"propertyNames": {
    "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z\\-]+$"
},
"patternProperties": {
    "": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/role"
    }
}
```

That will then allow you to use a pattern to define the property name and have it all dynamic.